# Bank statements for Schengen visa application

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planning to visit Spain (Mallorca and Barcelona) from 27 March to 3 April. I am from India and I am currently studying in the UK on a Tier 4 visa.

I generally use my FOREX card to withdraw money, but I have bank account in RBS too. I know that 3-months of bank slips are required for the Schengen visa application; I will apply on the 8th of February 2018.

Although I opened a bank account in RBS around 17 Sept 2017, I transferred about £840 into it on 1st Dec 2017. I used this money throughout the month of December, because I was on another trip, to London and Scotland. That meant that, during all of January 2018, my UK bank account had only £20, as I was also using my FOREX card.

I again credited my RBS account with £700 on 2nd Feb 2018. Will this sudden amount create a problem in getting Schengen visa?

Basically, I haven't maintained the minimum funds required for a Spanish Schengen visa, as my UK bank account was opened in September 2017. There was the £840 in December, the £20 during January and now it has the £700.

Comment: Where is your money coming from? Do you have it in a bank account somewhere else besides your RBS account? Can you submit that bank statement, the one associated with your forex card? If you just attach your RBS bank statement, it would look like you're routinely spending almost all your money yet want to take an international vacation, which looks quite suspicious. If you keep most of your funds in another account and just use the RBS account for spending money, that makes more sense.

Comment: I have two accounts. One is RBS and another one is HDFC (in India). I am using forex card (HDFC) mainly for monthly purpose.

Comment: Does the HDFC account show sufficient funds? It seems like that would solve your problems nicely.

Comment: Yes it has sufficient amount. I mean full 3 months statement can be seen (maintaining sufficient bank bank balance). I was only scared about the fact that HDFC forex card lies under the card type of "visa multicurrency" (although all amount is in GBP). So should I attach my RBS bank statement along with HDFC forex card statement? Will this be fine?

Comment: Also I read it somewhere that for schengen visa 3 months bank statement should be of UK bank account and not Indian bank account. Is it true? HDFC is an Indian bank though it provides services like money transfer etc to other countries also including UK.

Answer (score -3):

Unless you are a permanent resident, you need to apply from India.

Taken from the VFS Global Website (for Germany, but the rules are the same across the Schengen zone):

> Eligibility
>
> Applicant must at least meet the following criteria in order to be
>   eligible to submit a Schengen visa application:
>
> - holding a valid passport/travel document
> - holding a valid UK residence permit. In case applicant holds a short stay visa, a C type visa (see example here), for the UK, then
>     applicant needs to apply for a Schengen visa from his/her residence
>     country.
> - applying for a short stay visa (Tourist: including Minors, Visitor Family/Friends, Business, EEA/EU and Swiss national family member or
>     Airport Transit)

Finally found the page at BLS (the agents handling Spanish visas in UK), which states [under requirements](https://uk.blsspainvisa.com/london/tourist_type_visa.php):

> UK residence permit. You must be a resident in UK to be eligible to
>   apply. Your residence permit must be valid for at least another 90
>   days beyond your return date from Schengen area. Please provide
>   original and a copy (If card type, please copy both sides)

In India, you'll have to supply your HDFC account details.

Comment: This is not true. You simply need to be a resident and hold a resident permit in the UK to apply for a Schengen visa, and not a permanent residency. All tier 4 students in the UK get a residence permit for the UK, and are eligible to apply for a Schengen visa. In the quote that you have included above, it says residence permit, and not "permanent leave to remain" (which is the UK equivalent of a permanent residency).